# Iphone:how toValidate message authentication code(Mac)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, authentication, aes, code-signing

I have a Java code like this:

```
public static byte[] generateMac(byte[] key, byte[] cipherText,int offset,int length,int mac_size_bits)
{
    byte[] result = null;
    KeyParameter keyParam = null;
    try {
        keyParam = new KeyParameter(key);
        CBCBlockCipherMac blockCipherMac = new CBCBlockCipherMac(new AESEngine(),mac_size_bits);
        result = new byte[blockCipherMac.getMacSize()];
        blockCipherMac.init(keyParam);
        blockCipherMac.update(cipherText, offset, length);
        blockCipherMac.doFinal(result, 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    } finally {
        keyParam = null;
    }
    return result;
}
```

On the iPhone I am scribbling like this:

`- (NSData *)generateMac:(NSData *)key cipherText:(NSData *)cipherText offset:(int)offset length:(int)length mac_size_bits:(int)mac_size_bits`

My question is, which method should I use for `CBCBlockCipherMac`, `keyparameters` in iPhone can anyone help me please?

Comment: Which security alog is that , in iPhone / Objective c, there are libKrypto and if its AES, then its open source that you can use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its MAC encryption -- AFAIK there is no one-shot replacement/equivalent on IOS

see original docs [docs](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jonah/bc/org/bouncycastle/crypto/macs/CBCBlockCipherMac.html) 
and wikipedia [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBC-MAC)

learn how the algo works and then replicate it using CommonCrypto

--sorry no better idea